# Query only the first element in C# ObjectQuery like LIMIT = 1 in SQL

Tags: c#, linq

This (edit: I'm pasting the whole code between scope.Connect(); and {catch...)

```
var Query = new SelectQuery("SELECT LogonId  FROM Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType=2");
var Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, Query);
var regName = new Regex(@"(?<=Name="").*(?="")");

 foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
{
foreach (ManagementObject LWmiObject in WmiObject.GetRelationships("Win32_LoggedOnUser"))
{
users.Add(regName.Match(LWmiObject["Antecedent"].ToString()).Value);
}
}
```

is querying the logged on users however I would like to have it fast and because of the server settings which I can't alter sometimes I get more users such as update service or security service user. They appear as "normal" users so it is impossible to filter them as far as I know.

So the goal would be to select the very first record. How can I do that? I'm thinking of the C# version of LIMIT or TOP in SQL.

Thank you

Comment: Since ObjectQuery implements IQueryable, is there any reason you can't use LINQ's `.First()` or `.Take(1)` methods?

Comment: Thank you.
You're not going to like what I'm about to say and I'm sorry for it, but I have no idea how to do that. (haven't found a good example) Yet.

Comment: Don't loop if you only want one? Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that WQL/WMI has no TOP 1 equivalent so any optimizations would be at the collection level.

Comment: What are you trying to query though? The last logged in user? The first? Any random one? Most likely there *is* a way to retrieve the latest login

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can get the first logged on user like this.

```
ManagementObject LWmiObject = WmiObject.GetRelationships("Win32_LoggedOnUser").First();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are your looking for, but I think this solves that.

```
var users = Searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
            .Select(wmi => wmi.GetRelationships("Win32_LoggedOnUser")
                .Cast<ManagementObject>()
                .Select(lWmi => regName.Match(lWmi["Antecedent"].ToString()))
                .Where(m => m.Success)
                .Select(u => u.Value)
                .FirstOrDefault());
```